# Qt Plugin Widget Crashes App On Run

Tags: c++, qt

So I have a custom plugin that I built for a collection of my custom widgets. They all load fine in QtDesigner, and I can customize them well. However, when I go to run said app, it compiles and just ends.

Here is the App Output:

```
> Starting MaterialTest.exe...
> MaterialTest.exe exited with code 0
```

Also here is the compile output:

```
> Running steps for project MaterialTest...
> Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
> Starting: "D:\Qt\5.9.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    D:\Qt\5.9.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    D:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\bin\uic.exe ..\MaterialTest\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -
    Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -
    w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc -DUNICODE -
    DWIN32 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB 
    -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I..\MaterialTest -I. -I..\MaterialTest -
    I..\MaterialTest -ID:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\include -
    ID:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\include\QtWidgets -
    ID:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\include\QtGui -
    ID:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\include\QtANGLE -
    ID:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -
    ID:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\msvc2015\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Forelease\ 
    @C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.904300.63.jom
    mainwindow.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:release\MaterialTest.exe @C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Local\Temp\MaterialTest.exe.904300.1985.jom
> The process "D:\Qt\5.9.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
> Elapsed time: 00:05.
```

I have already built a library (debug and release) for the test app to use. It has been included to the project as well. This test project has nothing new that isn't likely to be in a new project, besides the plugin and the library so I will not add a MCVE as it isn't possible without the plugin and library. I will provide the plugin/library source code below:

https://github.com/NickJohn547745/MaterialWidgets

I will be more than glad to provide any more information if needed.

Comment: where is this icons.qrc?

Comment: I wonder where is the library *pro* file, instead. I can see only the plugin, or am I missing something?

Comment: @eyllanesc this was excluded from the project

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o the MaterialWidgets.pro includes the library parameters as well.

Comment: I am trying to use your code but I see that you have not generated the libraries of the widgets themselves, for example I can not link the .h.

Comment: @eyllanesc the GitHub project contains the wth project where upon build will produce the dll for the plugin and the lib for the library.

Comment: Is that I think you're confusing, one thing is the .dlls of the plugin, and you should have other .dlls for your widgets with the headers.

Comment: @eyllanesc hmm I might be on the wrong page. I generate lib files which I use in my Test app by linking them in their respective directories. I also generate a dll for my respective plugin of widgets to which I move to the `plugins/designer/`

Comment: @NicholasJohnson I wonder if you're linking an exe against the plugin ... which is no good: you need a regular library with your widgets to link against, and another project for the plugin (which won't ship, it's there for Designer only).

Comment: @NicholasJohnson 
The plugins only serve so that Qt Designer can emulate your widget and can manipulate the elements, and another thing is the widgets itself, I recommend separating your project into 2 subprojects as I showed you in a previous answer.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o So, I currently have the plugin project also just spitting out a library of itself to use for the exe. I also have a custom folder under qt’s include folder that I use for my headers

Comment: For example, check my next test project, I have 2 projects: one for the widget and another for the plugin. https://github.com/eyllanesc/QhPlugins

Comment: The library from the plugin project is meant to be a Qt Designer plugin. You need a separate dll to link an exe against.

Comment: @eyllanesc so basically, you would like me to make a project that is only there to generate my plugin dll for designer. And another project that is only there to generate a library that can be used for my apps to grab headers and link to? Also in the plugin.cpp, it asked for where I should get my include file. What should I put there assuming I have a library.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson Qt Designer only needs the .dll of the plugin so that the widget can be rendered. But your testing project, or rather the real project where you will use that widget you have created, needs the .dll and the widget header, it does not need the plugin. In your case I see that you have put them together and that is not appropriate.If you have ever deployed your project you will see that you only use the .dlls of the widget: QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, and never those of the design. So in the end you just have to link the widget's .dll.

Comment: @eyllanesc very good, should I go about adding all of my headers and source into one separate project and then I can build them into a dll? Also do I need a lib file at all?

Comment: @NicholasJohnson You need to create 2 projects: one for the plugin that generates the .dll, and another one that generates the .dll and the header for your widget, the latter must be linked in your real project.

Comment: @eyllanesc I’m sorry, could you post an answer and go into detail on how I should go about the generation of the widget dll and header linkage to the project? I think that should be all I need

Comment: @NicholasJohnson I'm going to take the time to design your project, but I'll try it in Linux, so you'll have to modify some things in the .pro to make it work, for example the target.path that will differ.

Comment: @eyllanesc I cannot tell you how much I appreciate it. I’ve been attempting different plugin usages but I honestly think the documentation is horrible. I will gladly wait to offer a bounty

Comment: @NicholasJohnson When I did it for the first time I also thought the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166845/discussion-between-nicholas-johnson-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @NicholasJohnson I have already restructured the code, I would like to test it on windows through teamviewer, if you can let me know. In linux it is simple since the .so equivalents to the .dlls is enough to put it in / usr / lib and it is linked, but in windows I do not know.

Comment: @eyllanesc No need, I have already used your example to get the project up and running. I have a new issue that I made a post for.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson 
Well, that seems like a windows problem. If I publish my answer would you accept it?

Comment: @eyllanesc Absolutely! If you don't mind I might attempt an edit to include Linux and Windows.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson I put it for linux and you add it for windows, do you think it's good?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, that will be perfect.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson Okay, I'm going to order what I have to be consistent, I'll publish it in a few hours.

Comment: @eyllanesc Okay